# How do I print different names from a list?

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

Here is my list of gamers and what games they like:

> player1: WoW, RS, MS
>
> player2: AQ, CoD, LoL, RS
>
> player3: D3, Mario, WoW
>
> player4: LoL, MS

The list property is `public List<string> Games { get; set; }`

Now this is what I've tried in my code

```
var result = Gamer.GetGamer()
                  .Select(x => x.Games)
                  .Distinct()
                  .Dump("List of Different Games Played");
```

The `GetGamer()` method returns the list of gamers.

Now the problem here is that it will display the list of games but will repeat instead of having different values.

What I really want is the total number of *different* games being played. How do I display them without repeats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` instead of `Select`:

```
Gamer.GetGamer()
     .SelectMany(x => x.Games)
     .Distinct()
     .Dump();
```

If you want to get `Count` just add `Count` after `Distinct`